# Mercurial or Bitbucket - push set of commits to a separate fork

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg, git-fork

Let's say a repository A has some history

```
 commit4
    ^
 commit3
    ^
 commit2
    ^
 commit1
    ^
 commit0
```

If I now wanted to "split" repository A at commit2, i.e. I want a repository B to be a fork of A, where

history of A:

```
 commit2
    ^
 commit1
    ^
 commit0
```

history of B:

```
 commit4
    ^
 commit3
    ^
 commit2
    ^
 commit1
    ^
 commit0
```

How would I best do that using either bitbucket or the Mercurial Workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **TortoiseHg Workbench** you could do the following:

1. Right click on A in the **Repository Registry** in the Workbench and click **Clone**.
2. Set the destination to B and click **Clone**.
3. Double click on A in the **Repository Registry** to view it's commits.
4. Right click on *commit3*, select **Modify History** then select **Strip**. This will delete every commit after *commit3* and including *commit3*.
5. You now have repositories A and B with the desired structure.

---

Using **BitBucket** you could do the following:

1. Go to the **Overview** page for A and click **Fork** in the menu on the left to create a fork of A called B.
   A and B will now both have the same full set of commits as A.
2. Again go back to the **Overview** for A and click **Settings** at the bottom of the menu on the left.
3. In the **Settings** menu click on **Strip Changesets**.
4. Enter *commit3* into the box and click **Preview Strip**.
5. This will show you the commits that will be deleted, double check that it shows the expected commits, in this case *commit3* and *commit4*.
6. Click **Confirm Strip** to delete the commits.

---

Problems to watch out for with these strategies are:

1. Make sure you have a full backup of A somewhere because the strip action is destructive.
2. If there are existing clones of A out there and one of them gets pushed to A on BitBucket then the stripped changes will be pushed in again.  You need to make sure that all the clones also have the strip carried out on them, or that fresh clones are made.
3. If you push from B to A then the stripped changes could be pushed back in since they're both from the same root.